# Mongodb's Aggregation Framework with Subset and Scala

Tags: mongodb, scala, subset

I'm trying to use the Mongo's Aggregation Framework with Subset, I've look to the project's test:

https://github.com/osinka/subset/blob/master/src/test/scala/aggregation/pipelinesSpec.scala

And the example in the doc:

http://osinka.github.io/subset/Examples.html

But still can't figure out how to get from that TraversableOnce to an actual query, this is what I have been trying.

The working mongo query:

```
db.products.aggregate(
    {$unwind: "$c_ids"},
    {$match:{c_ids:{$in: [
    ObjectId("51e463ba2b3a972d7300091f"),
    ObjectId("51cd8dbe2b3a977368000024"),
    ObjectId("51e70d052b3a974795000452"),
    ObjectId("51cda94f2b3a97739a000025")
    ]}}},
    {$group:{_id:"$c_ids",total:{$sum:1},sale:{$sum:{
$cond: [{$eq: ["$on_sale",true]},1,0]
}}}})
```

The above works as expected, and this is what I have figured out so far:

```
val cId = "c_ids".fieldOf[ObjectId]
val total = "total".fieldOf[Int]
val sale = "sale".fieldOf[Int]
val on_sale = "on_sale".fieldOf[Boolean]
val query = db("products").aggregate(
      Unwind(cId),
      Match(cId in List[ObjectId](new ObjectId("51cda94f2b3a97739a000025"))),
      Group(cId, 
      total -> Group.Sum(1), 
      sale -> Group.Sum(Project.Cond(Project.Eq(on_sale, true), 1, 2)))
    )
```

The above compiles and everything, but I cannot understand what's next... I haven't ever use Subset before... a clue or tip in the right direction would be great.

Answer (score 0):

> Subset does not provide methods to perform queries to MongoDB, its
>   only concern is about Mongo Java Driver’s method parameters including
>   documents and their fields.

So once you have built the aggregation query - you can now run it, the val `query` should be a [AggregationOutput](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/index.html?com/mongodb/AggregationOutput.html) result - which you can call `results()` to get the actual aggregation results.

See [using the aggregation framework with the java driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-aggregation-framework-with-java-driver/) for more information.